# Panda Get_Value throwing error : '[xxxx]' is an invalid key

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use Python  DataFrame.Get_Value(Index,ColumnName) to get value of column and it keep throwing following Error

"'[10004]' is an invalid key" where 10004 is index value.

This is how Dataframe looks:
[image]

I have successfully used get_value before.. I dont know whats wrong with this dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

First, `pandas.DataFrame.get_value` [is deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.get_value.html) (and should have been `get_value`, as opposed to `Get_Value`). It's better to use a non-deprecated method such as `.loc` or `.at` instead:

```
df.loc[10004, 'Column_Name']
# Or:
df.at[10004, 'Column_Name']
```

Your issue with might be that you have `10004` stored as a string instead of an integer. Try surrounding the index by quotes (`df.loc['10004', 'Column_Name']`). You can check this easily by saying: `df.index.dtype`, and seeing if it returns `dtype('O')`